# As a physician looking for extra work, how do locum tenens sites work?

Tags: hospital

I'll be taking a lengthy break from my full-time job as a physician at a hospital, and I'm considering locum tenens. I'm in the US, but I can go to any state (preferably east coast) if the pay's good enough.

Q1: How do locum tenens websites work? I see so many different options (locumtenens.com, CompHealth, plus many others I see [here](https://www.clearlyrated.com/staffing/healthcare-staffing/locum-tenens-physicians-staffing)), but I don't know what the difference is between one and the other.

Q2: As the doctor looking for work, do I pay the locum tenens company so that I can work at hospital X or hospital Y? Do I pay an upfront fee to access these sites? Once I decide to work at hospital Z, will the locum site withhold an amount from my paycheck? If so, how much would this amount be? Is it per hour, is it a percentage, is it a fixed amount? What's the range?

Q3: I've also heard of job sites like indeed and monster. For jobs like engineering and accounting these websites don't usually charge the person applying for a job. Does that also apply to me as a doctor?